# Laplace transform of 1 $\frac{1}{p}$ or $-\frac{1}{p}$?

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm trying to solve this problem

$\begin{cases} X'(t) + Y(t) = 2e^{2t}+e^{t}+1 \\ X(t)-Y'(t)=e^{2t}-e^{t}+1 \end{cases}$

The first thing I've done is the Laplace transform ($x(p)$ for $L[X(t)]$ and $y(p)$ for $L[Y(t)]$)

$\begin{cases} px(p)+y(p) = \frac{2}{p-2}+\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{p}\\ x(p)-py(p)=\frac{1}{p-2}-\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{p}\end{cases}$

But when I saw the solutions my professor gave us, they had used $-\frac{1}{p}$ as the Laplace transform of 1, why is that so?

Thank you

Comment: It should be $1/p$ I'm pretty sure. I don't know what your teacher did withouth context.

Comment: @Milten That's as much context as I had, it just said $-\frac{1}{p}$ instead of $\frac{1}{p}$ when doing the Laplace transform of the system

Comment: Domain of convergence: $L[1_{t > 0}] = 1/p$ for $p > 0$ and $L[-1_{t<0}] = 1/p$ for $p< 0$.

Comment: @reuns so it is always $\frac{1}{p}$?

Comment: $\int_0^\infty e^{-tp}dt=1/p$ for $p > 0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-tp}dt=-1/p$ for $p < 0$

Comment: @reuns But in the problem they didn't tell us the domain, so how would I know which one to use?

Comment: Due to the other terms there are many possible domain of convergence: $(-\infty,0),(0,1),(1,2),(2,\infty)$. The best is to solve it for each. Your question suggests that they chose $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: @reuns How can I know the domains of convergence?